# extractSingle/extractArray in seralizers/application.js not getting called

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember/EmberData (version 2.1.0) application that is to display a list of `posts` (created from a json payload) on the home page, with the route

```
this.route("posts", { path: "/" });
```

However, the `posts` retrieved from the server are not in the format expected by EmberData i.e. they do not have a top level namespace. Therefore, I created a file

```
serializers/application.js
```

and included an `extractSingle` and an `extractArray` function in it, but neither of them are getting called, and the error message is therefore not goig away

`Error while processing route: posts Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push`

This error was preceeded by a warning:

```
`WARNING: "Encountered "0" [and "1"] in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved model name using em@serializer:posts.modelNameFRomPayloadKey("0")
```

I also created a file

```
 serializers/posts.js
```

and included the same functions there, as well (extending the ApplicationAdapter) but neither of them are getting called also

Code from /serializers/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id){
          var convertedPayload = {};
          convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
          convertedPayload.id = id;
          return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload, id}
      },
      extractArray: function(store, type, payload){
         var convertedPayload = {};
         convertedPayload[type.modelName = payload;
         return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
      },
      serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options){
         //ommitted
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the transitioning guide: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_transition-to-the-new-jsonserializer-and-restserializer-apis

There are no extractSingle/Array hooks anymore.